# Getting error while using new Audio in nuxt created hook

Tags: vue.js, audio, nuxt.js

i'm getting error while using `this.audio = new Audio();` in nuxt created hook.
but in vue (pure vue), i didn't get error.
what should i do?

created hook:

```
data(){
   return {
      audio: ''
   }
},
created() {
   this.audio = new Audio();
}
```

and this is my error:

```
Audio is not defined
```

Comment: And which error do you get? ... Please edit the question with the related error and full details.

Comment: @ChristopherDosin Error message added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because created hook executed both on client and server. So when executed on server it will throw a error, because there no Audio class on node server.

You could either move it to mounted, because mounted executed only on client or wrap with

```
if (process.server) {
}
```

Comment: but my methods are not working :(
```
    getCurrentSong(id) {
      this.currentSong.index = id;
    }
```

```
currentSong: {
        index: 0,
        src: '',
 }, 
      },
```

Comment: @mrstark create a proper new question with full code